# find specific item in Json Array in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a json file where I want to search for a device (ex. AEVL2020) and will return multiple results based on "registers". I tried to search on the net but didn't find any clue.
 So I want an output like this:

```
 "12":{
                "user_id": "1",
                "employee_id": "12",
                "name": "Juan Dela Cruz",
                "privilege": "0"
            },
            "32":{
                "user_id": "2",
                "employee_id": "32",
                "name": "Pedro Dela Cruz",
                "privilege": "0"
            }
```

Here is my json:

```
{
        "devices": {
            "AEVL2020":{
                "deviceSerialId": "AEVL2020"
            },
            "AEVL2021":{
                "deviceSerialId": "AEVL2021"
            }
        },
        "registers":{
            "AEVL2020":{
                "12":{
                    "user_id": "1",
                    "employee_id": "12",
                    "name": "Juan Dela Cruz",
                    "privilege": "0"
                },
                "32":{
                    "user_id": "2",
                    "employee_id": "32",
                    "name": "Pedro Dela Cruz",
                    "privilege": "0"
                }
            },
            "AEVL2021":{
                "29":{
                    "user_id": "1",
                    "employee_id": "29",
                    "name": "Maria Dela Cruz",
                    "privilege": "0"
                },
                "222":{
                    "user_id": "2",
                    "employee_id": "222",
                    "name": "Jay Dela Cruz",
                    "privilege": "0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using Newtonsoft.Json

```
var json = JObject.Parse("{\"devices\":{\"AEVL2020\":{\"deviceSerialId\":\"AEVL2020\"},\"AEVL2021\":{\"deviceSerialId\":\"AEVL2021\"}},\"registers\":{\"AEVL2020\":{\"12\":{\"user_id\":\"1\",\"employee_id\":\"12\",\"name\":\"Juan Dela Cruz\",\"privilege\":\"0\"},\"32\":{\"user_id\":\"2\",\"employee_id\":\"32\",\"name\":\"Pedro Dela Cruz\",\"privilege\":\"0\"}},\"AEVL2021\":{\"29\":{\"user_id\":\"1\",\"employee_id\":\"29\",\"name\":\"Maria Dela Cruz\",\"privilege\":\"0\"},\"222\":{\"user_id\":\"2\",\"employee_id\":\"222\",\"name\":\"Jay Dela Cruz\",\"privilege\":\"0\"}}}}");

var devices = json.Value<JObject>("devices");
var registers = json.Value<JObject>("registers");

foreach (var device in devices)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Device {device.Key}:");
    Console.WriteLine(registers[device.Value.Value<string>("deviceSerialId")]);
}
```

I have output like you want

```
Device AEVL2020:
{
  "12": {
    "user_id": "1",
    "employee_id": "12",
    "name": "Juan Dela Cruz",
    "privilege": "0"
  },
  "32": {
    "user_id": "2",
    "employee_id": "32",
    "name": "Pedro Dela Cruz",
    "privilege": "0"
  }
}

Device AEVL2021:
{
  "29": {
    "user_id": "1",
    "employee_id": "29",
    "name": "Maria Dela Cruz",
    "privilege": "0"
  },
  "222": {
    "user_id": "2",
    "employee_id": "222",
    "name": "Jay Dela Cruz",
    "privilege": "0"
  }
}
```

p.s.: probably you would read json from file, so replace the first line to

```
var json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("file.json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another similar way:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
var reg = obj["registers"]["AEVL2020"];
```

Or using a loop:

```
foreach (var deviceName in obj["devices"].Children<JProperty>().Select(x => x.Name))
{
    var reg = obj["registers"][deviceName];
}
```